# get and install SSL certificate

Tags: java, ssl, certificate

So I also came across the below java code to retrieve and import the certs published by a server and import them into truststore.

```
import javax.net.ssl.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.security.KeyStore;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.cert.CertificateException;
import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;

/**
 * Class used to add the server's certificate to the KeyStore
 * with your trusted certificates.
 */
public class InstallCert {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        String host;
        int port;
        char[] passphrase;
        if ((args.length == 1) || (args.length == 2)) {
            String[] c = args[0].split(":");
            host = c[0];
            port = (c.length == 1) ? 443 : Integer.parseInt(c[1]);
            String p = (args.length == 1) ? "changeit" : args[1];
            passphrase = p.toCharArray();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Usage: java InstallCert [:port] [passphrase]");
            return;
        }

        File file = new File("jssecacerts");
        if (file.isFile() == false) {
            char SEP = File.separatorChar;
            File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP
                    + "lib" + SEP + "security");
            file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
            if (file.isFile() == false) {
                file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Loading KeyStore " + file + "...");
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, passphrase);
        in.close();

        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        TrustManagerFactory tmf =
                TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[]{tm}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();

        System.out.println("Opening connection to " + host + ":" + port + "...");
        SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(host, port);
        socket.setSoTimeout(10000);
        try {
            System.out.println("Starting SSL handshake...");
            socket.startHandshake();
            socket.close();
            System.out.println();
            System.out.println("No errors, certificate is already trusted");
        } catch (SSLException e) {
            System.out.println();
            e.printStackTrace(System.out);
        }

        X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null) {
            System.out.println("Could not obtain server certificate chain");
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader reader =
                new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Server sent " + chain.length + " certificate(s):");
        System.out.println();
        MessageDigest sha1 = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA1");
        MessageDigest md5 = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
        for (int i = 0; i < chain.length; i++) {
            X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
            System.out.println
                    (" " + (i + 1) + " Subject " + cert.getSubjectDN());
            System.out.println("   Issuer  " + cert.getIssuerDN());
            sha1.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   sha1    " + toHexString(sha1.digest()));
            md5.update(cert.getEncoded());
            System.out.println("   md5     " + toHexString(md5.digest()));
            System.out.println();
        }

        System.out.println("Enter certificate to add to trusted keystore or 'q' to quit: [1]");
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        int k;
        try {
            k = (line.length() == 0) ? 0 : Integer.parseInt(line) - 1;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            System.out.println("KeyStore not changed");
            return;
        }

        X509Certificate cert = chain[k];
        String alias = host + "-" + (k + 1);
        ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
        ks.store(out, passphrase);
        out.close();

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println(cert);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println
                ("Added certificate to keystore 'jssecacerts' using alias '"
                        + alias + "'");
    }

    private static final char[] HEXDIGITS = "0123456789abcdef".toCharArray();

    private static String toHexString(byte[] bytes) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.length * 3);
        for (int b : bytes) {
            b &= 0xff;
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b >> 4]);
            sb.append(HEXDIGITS[b & 15]);
            sb.append(' ');
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager {

        private final X509TrustManager tm;
        private X509Certificate[] chain;

        SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm) {
            this.tm = tm;
        }

        public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
        }

        public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                throws CertificateException {
            this.chain = chain;
            tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
        }
    }
}
```

During the first run, I get 2 certs published by the server and I import them into my truststore without issues (I can see the certs in the truststore via keytool). However on the 2nd run, I would expect to get the "No errors, certificate is already trusted" output, however instead I get an UnsupportedOperationException as below, propagated from the getAcceptedIssuers() method of the inner class, and then prompted again to import the certs.
Could someone please help me understand why?

```
Starting SSL handshake...

javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Alerts.java:208)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1904)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(SSLSocketImpl.java:1862)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(SSLSocketImpl.java:1845)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1366)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1343)
        at LDAPCerts.start(LDAPCerts.java:41)
        at LDAPCerts.main(LDAPCerts.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at LDAPCerts$SavingTrustManager.getAcceptedIssuers(LDAPCerts.java:126)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAlgorithmConstraints(SSLContextImpl.java:998)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkAdditionalTrust(SSLContextImpl.java:944)
        at sun.security.ssl.AbstractTrustManagerWrapper.checkServerTrusted(SSLContextImpl.java:886)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.serverCertificate(ClientHandshaker.java:1428)
        at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:209)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:901)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:837)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1023)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1359)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: Did you notice that it not happens with java 1.6 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple, on your implementation of X509TrustManager

You just have to return an X509Certificate array. And that's all!

```
    @Override
    public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return new X509Certificate[0];
        // throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
    }
```

from...
http://infposs.blogspot.com/2013/06/installcert-and-java-7.html

Answer (score 0):

After the file jssecacerts has been created, copy it to $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/ directory and try again.

**UPDATE:**

Well, it is not necessary but then you need to specify the location by a JVM system parameter:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=
```

Please see how the location is determined. Taken from the [Oracle guide](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/JSSERefGuide.html#X509TrustManager):

> 1. If the system property: javax.net.ssl.trustStore
>
> is defined, then the TrustManagerFactory attempts to find a file using
>   the filename specified by that system property, and uses that file for
>   the KeyStore. If the javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword system property
>   is also defined, its value is used to check the integrity of the data
>   in the truststore before opening it.
>
> If javax.net.ssl.trustStore is
>   defined but the specified file does not exist, then a default
>   TrustManager using an empty keystore is created.
>
> 2. If the javax.net.ssl.trustStore system property was not specified,
>      then if the file /lib/security/jssecacerts
>
> exists, that file is used. (See The Installation Directory 
>   for information about what  refers to.) Otherwise,
>
> 3. If the
>      file /lib/security/cacerts
>
> exists, that file is used.

Comment: Hi Laszlo, thanks for your answer. Actually I am using a custom truststore under a different path to read from and write to it the published certificates. Why would I need to put it $JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/ dir? Couldn't I have truststores stored elsewhere and used by my apps?

Comment: Thanks again Laszlo, I did try indeed to run the program as below, by passing it the three -D properties : `java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/my/truststore -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=jks -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=changeit -Djavax.net.ssl.debug=all LDAPCerts`  
But the exception persists...

Comment: Have you used the path format for your operating system? And used the file name as well in the path? For Windows: -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\mydir\jssecacerts   For Linux:-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=path\to\jssecacerts If yes, you cal also try my original suggestion to copy that file into the jre folder to see if it is seen.

Comment: It's on linux, so I used : -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/path/to/my/truststore
Should I use \ instead of / for linux? Also I tried to pass it programmatically via :
`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "/path/to/my/truststore");` - Still no luck...